# System.Windows.Vector in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, porting

I'm trying to port some code to silverlight.

Is there an equilavent of System.Windows.Vector for silverlight?

Comment: why not just use System.Windows.Vector ??

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a System.Windows.Vector class in the silverlight.

System.Windows.Vector is defined in WindowsBase.dll which is not a silverlight assembly, so I can't use it in silverlight

Answer (score 1):

I use Vector2 and Vector3 from the MonoXNA project:

http://monoxna.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/Microsoft.Xna.Framework/

Comment: Vector2 is an alternative, but no 1:1 surrogate. Vector2 uses for instance floats, whereas Vector uses doubles.